# iOS ReactNative Firebase Library pod upgrade issue on M1 Mac

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, cocoapods, apple-m1

I have tried

```
 rm -rf Podfile.lock
 pod install --repo-update
```

and all other suggestions. but nothing worked. I'm getting this error message.

[!] Unable to find a specification for `FirebaseCoreExtension (= 10.3.0)` depended upon by `RNFBMessaging`

You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Here's my pod file
[image: Podfile]

Here's my react-native info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.0.1
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
    Memory: 157.45 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.11.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.01.30.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK: Not Found
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
    Xcode: /undefined - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.13 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: 0.63.5 => 0.63.5 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Comment: try the following steps:

Remove the node_modules folder and install again using this command

    npm install --legacy-peer-deps
    
Remove pods from iOS folder and install pods again using this command

    arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: @tushali_jasoliya didn't work that

Comment: arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update 
try with this